# Paramiko's SFTP Python connection

Tags: python, ssh, sftp, paramiko

I'm trying to set up an SFTP connection with Python (v2.7) using Paramiko's library http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.1/api/sftp.html

From bits and pieces online I was able to (I think so anyway) connect using a private encrypted certificate.

This looks as follows:

```
import paramiko
sftp = paramiko.SSHClient()

hostname = "sftp.host.com"
port = 8022
username = "sftplogin"

k = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file("private.pem", password="XXX")
sftp.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
print "Connecting..."
sftp.connect(hostname, port, username=username, pkey=k )
print "Connected to: " + hostname + ":" + port
print sftp.getcwd()
sftp.close()
```

At this point, I'm just trying to see if I'm not delusional and in fact did not connect, so I'm attempting to print a getcwd() to get the current directory ... Sadly I'm getting nowhere, as it's returning this error:

> AttributeError: 'SSHClient' object has no attribute 'getcwd'

Can anyone tell me why? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This has worked for me.

```
import os
import paramiko

host = "sftp.host.com"
port = 8022
transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))
username = "sftplogin"
mykey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file("private_export.pem", password="XXX")
print "Connecting..."
transport.connect(username = username, pkey = mykey)
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
print "Connected."
print sftp.listdir()
sftp.close()
transport.close()
print "Closed connection."
```

Comment: or without key: `transport.connect(username = username, password=password)`

Answer (score 1):

You instantiated a [`paramiko.SSHClient`](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.1/api/client.html) object, but you're trying to execute [SFTP Client methods](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.1/api/sftp.html).

You should be able to execute this to demonstrate that fact:

```
sftp.exec_command('pwd')
```

But I think you meant to instantiate the SFTP class, rather than the SSH client, so that is probably where you went wrong.